# Serialize a var (jquery)?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I have to use jquery serialize for this var... how to?

```
    var type = { op:"add" , id_user : <?=$u->id?> , tipo : tipo , description : $("#desc_new_param").val() }
                    $.ajax({type: "POST",cache: false,url: "<?=SYSTEM_WEB_ADMIN?>second.php",data: type,success: function(data) {
                        $("#tab-"+tipo).html(data);
   }});
```

Comment: By serialize do you mean turn it into a string?

Comment: so um: `var str = type.serialize();` ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by serialize you mean convert between string and object. Use the JSON object methods:

```js
var type = { 
    op:"add" , 
    id_user : 1431 , 
    tipo : "tipo something" , 
    description : "some sort of description" 
};

var myTypeString = JSON.stringify(type);

console.log("myTypeString is a "+typeof(myTypeString), myTypeString);

console.log("As a JSON object: ", JSON.parse(myTypeString) );
```